# Open all EXTERNAL links in a new tab - Shopify

Tags: javascript, url, shopify, liquid

I am trying to modify a site to make it open external links in a new tab.

Currently I have a loop which works fine except that it opens ALL links in a new tab which is not desired:
I have tried using filters but can't seem to get it to work properly.

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
  links[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
}
});
</script>
```

Maybe checking if the URL contains a Shopify handle or something along the line?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the href attributes begins with `http://`, `https://` or `www.` since those are the most common external links, all internal usually starts with `/`. (you can add an additional check if the href contains the domain name as well since it possible to have internal URL with the full URL)

So the code will become something like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    const link = links[i];
    const href = link.getAttribute('href');
    if(href.match(/^((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))/) {
      link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Looking at this it makes perfect sense but as soon as I implement it , it won't work and it is driving me nuts. I have a feeling that some internal function is overwriting this. I bought a damn payed theme to save me time doing exactly this, wasn't wort it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a"); //get all <a> elements

links.forEach(el => { //loop trought all <a> elements
  if(!el.href.includes(window.location.hostname)){ //if not this domain
   el.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  }
})
```

```css
/*just to show elements with target=_blank*/
[target="_blank"]{
color: green
}
```

```html
<a href="//google.com">other domain</a>
<a href="//stacksnippets.net">this domain</a>
```

Note: you don't need that `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'...` just put `defer` attribute on your `<script>` tag

Comment: I did not know that, thank you! Sadly it still won't apply to buttons. I wish there was an equivalent for` target="_blank"` for css. It would save me so much pain. As long as i target all links the `_blank` gets applied but as soon as filters get involved it breaks.

Comment: @itsolidude it looks like there is some equivalent look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp but it seems outdated.

Answer (score 0):

To get only External links Open in new Tabs, you must use anchor’s property hostname, when its value not matching your “localhostname” string then overwriting anchor's property target default value "_self"(current browser content) to "_blank"(new tab) value, your script code will be:

```
<script> 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
 if (links[i].hostname!="localhostname"){ 
    links[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
   } 
  }
 }); 
</script>
```